# iOS crash-reporter for own server

Tags: ios, crash-dumps, crash-reports

My company doesn't allow that crash reports are stored on third party servers so I need a solution that I can host on own servers. Is there any solution that tracks all errors in my ios-app and sends them to my own there where I can inspect them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/).

Comment: The API it depends on haven't changed since iOS 2.0. ARC support is another matter, though.

Comment: ARC is no problem for PLCrashReporter. Check out http://quincykit.net/ which uses PLCrashReporter (newer build than the one on the website) and adds all you need on top. Sending the reports to a server and a php open source server component. It also has basic grouping of similar crashes.